# Usage of ng-change and ng-model in a custom directive - digest loop

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on date picker to implement range selector on AngularUI.

An html code to call custom time picker:

> ```
> <time-range 
>          name-time="Hours" 
>          max-length="2" min="00" max="23" step="01" 
>          ng-model="hours" 
>          ng-change="updateHours()">
>   </time-range>
> ```

```
  <time-range 
         name-time="Minutes" 
         max-length="2" min="00" max="59" step="01" 
         ng-model="minutes" 
         ng-change="updateMinutes()">
   </time-range>
```

Here is my directive:

> module app.common.directives {
>
> ```
>     export interface ITimeRangeScope extends ng.IScope {
>         ngModel: string;
>         ngChange;
>         nameTime: string;
>         maxLength: number;
>         min: number;
>         max: number;
>         step: number;
>         vm: TimeRangeController;
>     }
>
>     export class TimeRange implements ng.IDirective {
>         scope: any = {
>             ngModel: "=",
>             ngChange: "=",
>             nameTime: "@",
>             maxLength: "@",
>             min: "@",
>             max: "@",
>             step: "@"
>         };
>         controller = TimeRangeController;
>
>         template = `
>             <div class="custom-range-slider">
>                 <span> {{nameTime}}: </span>
>                 <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"></div>
>                 <input type="range" max-length="{{maxLength}}" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" step="{{step}}" ng-model="ngModel"ng-change="ngChange">
>             </div>
>         `;
>
>         restrict: string = "E";
>
>         //Use this to register this directive
>         static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
>             var directive: ng.IDirectiveFactory = () => new TimeRange();
>             return directive;
>         }
>     }
>
>     class TimeRangeController {
>         init;
>         val;
>
>         // @ngInject
>         constructor(
>             private $scope: ITimeRangeScope,
>             private $element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery,
>             private $attrs,
>             private $transclude
>         ) {
>             $scope.vm = this;
>
>             this.$scope.$watch("ngModel", () => {
>                 this.showPercentage();
>                 this.drawRangeTrace();
>             });
>         }
>
>         showPercentage() {
>             this.init = parseInt(this.$scope.ngModel);
>             var min = parseInt(this.$element.attr('min'));
>             var max = parseInt(this.$element.attr('max'));
>             this.val = (this.init - min) / max - min;
>         }
>
>         drawRangeTrace() {
>             this.$element.children().find('input').css('background-image',
>                 '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, '
>                 + 'color-stop(' + this.val + ', #2196F3), '
>                 + 'color-stop(' + this.val + ', #C5C5C5)'
>                 + ')'
>             );
>             this.$element.children().find('input').val(this.init);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

This is how it is working:

[image: Date Picker with sliders]

But I recived an error of:  *10 $digest()*

```
> vendor.min.js:84275 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"},{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"},{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"}],[{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"},{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"},{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"}],[{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"},{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"},{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"}],[{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"},{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"},{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"}],[{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"},{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"},{"msg":"fn: ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"}]]
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22ms…%3A00.000Z%22%2C%22oldVal%22%3A%222017-05-28T22%3A00%3A00.000Z%22%7D%5D%5D
    at vendor.min.js:84275
    at Scope.$digest (vendor.min.js:102059)
    at Scope.$apply (vendor.min.js:102287)
    at vendor.min.js:104131
    at completeOutstandingRequest (vendor.min.js:90318)
    at vendor.min.js:90597
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed ngChange into onUpdate.

In html:

```
on-update="updateHours()"
```

I added in changed from ngCgange; in directive to

```
onUpdate: () => any;
```

Bind the scope:

`onUpdate: "&",`

aldo called a method *add*

```
class TimeRangeController {
        init;
        val;
        onUpdate; // Override callback for adding an entity to the list

        // @ngInject
        constructor(
            private $scope: ITimeRangeScope,
            private $element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery,
            private $attrs,
            private $transclude
        ) {
            $scope.vm = this;

            this.$scope.$watch("ngModel", () => {
                this.showPercentage();
                this.drawRangeTrace();
                this.add();
            });
        }

        add() {
             if (this.$attrs.onUpdate != undefined) {
                  this.$scope.onUpdate();
              }
        }

        showPercentage() {
            this.init = parseInt(this.$scope.ngModel);
            var min = parseInt(this.$element.attr('min'));
            var max = parseInt(this.$element.attr('max'));
            this.val = (this.init - min) / max - min;
        }

        drawRangeTrace() {
            this.$element.children().find('input').css('background-image',
                '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, '
                + 'color-stop(' + this.val + ', #2196F3), '
                + 'color-stop(' + this.val + ', #C5C5C5)'
                + ')'
            );
            this.$element.children().find('input').val(this.init);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Search answer in your Exception:

> Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn:
>   ngModelWatch","newVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z","oldVal":"2017-05-28T22:00:00.000Z"}...]]

Looks like you have problem in:

```
this.$scope.$watch("ngModel", () => {
            this.showPercentage();
            this.drawRangeTrace();
        });
```

You listen on `this.$scope.ngModel` and for some reason methods `this.showPercentage()` or `this.drawRangeTrace()` change your `ngModel` that fires additional watcher.

To avoid memory leaks Angular throws this Exception to get rid from infinite digest cycle loop.

---

Try to simplify your code to find problematic code snippet by start comment line by line content of methods `this.showPercentage()` and `this.drawRangeTrace()`

Comment: Now I removed ng-change from directive also from template in directive  and I added this "hardcode" on ngModel watcher this.$scope.$parent.updateMinutes();
this.$scope.$parent.updateHours();